# "Fixing" GRUB2? Machine becomes unresponsive

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, ubuntu-9.10, grub2

When I upgrade to Ubuntu 10.04, every so often the computer will become unresponsive:

1. SSH server does not receive connections.
2. When I physically sit down in front of the computer, it's still running but the screen is dark and machine appears to be unresponsive to mouse and keyboard.
3. Reboot is the only way I can access the machine again.

I have been made to believe this may be a problem with GRUB2 because I am able to run Ubuntu 9.10 with GRUB 1.97 Beta and this problem does not occur. There are many pages about fixing GRUB2 after installing Windows, but in my case I do have a dual-boot system but the installation involves upgrading the Ubuntu on the Linux-side only.

Could this really be the problem, and if so, is there a fix? Thanks community.

Comment: Upgrade to 10.10.

Comment: Upgrade to 11.04.

Comment: Thanks -- is there anything to indicate that these upgrades would work where 10.04 did not?

Comment: Should I try an upgrade progressively from 9.10, or fresh install? Thankfully I have `/home` partitioned separately (I learned after a few failed upgrades, but it's still painful, especially if I have to go back and reinstall 9.10...).